# Delete special characters of a Json string in PHP

Tags: php, json

How can I delete the Json special character of the first properities in PHP?
Here is my json string :

```
"[{"name":"Maria","y":"14"},{"name":"Frederick","y":"1"}]"
```

well, I want it to became as the following :

```
"[{name:"Maria",y:"14"},{name:"Frederick",y:"1"}]"
```

someone can help as soon as possible please?

Comment: Why do you want to invalidate your json?!

Comment: I need to complete the data of pie highchart http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/pie-basic/

Comment: ... wonders if there are any json invalidator tools out there ...

Comment: I don't wanna to use the Ajax if there is any other way to get my data

Comment: Your json data is invalid. Can I see your code where you generate this json data?

Comment: No, I what that code where you encode your data in json.

Comment: Have you tried it with the quotes? It seems unlikely that highcharts would choke on quoted keys...

Comment: this is the array of this before json-encode it : [array('name'=>'Maria','y'=>'14'),array('name'=>'Frederick','y'=>'1')]

Comment: You should try quoting some of the keys in your example, it works just fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see the value of `"y"` is string.. you can convert it into an integer so the highchart works fine, you can use `(integer)` before the value

Comment: greaate ! this is helped as well, I was wrong by thinking that the " of name & y were the cause !

Comment: happy to hear that :)

Answer (score 0):

Just try to encode json like following,

```
[array(name=>'Maria',y=>'14'),array(name=>'Frederick',y=>'1')]
```

it will invalid your json, but try to encode it if it works.

OR for valid json generate try out following,

```
while($data) {
    $rows[] = array("name"=>$data['name'],"y"=>$data['y']);
}
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
echo _format_json(stripslashes(json_encode($rows)));
```

This will generate a valid json data.

Answer (score -1):

Remove " from start and end after that it works ...